# Compare two lists with comma separated strings if one list contains only one string

Tags: javascript, jquery

with the following script I want to compare two list of strings, which are contain comma separated strings. If there are equal strings, I want to create an other html-element. It works fine, if both list of strings have more than one string. If one list contains only 1 string without comma, only the else-condition will be applied.

**Example1 (works):**

List of strings 1 = test1, test2, test3
; List of strings 2 = test1, test2

Expected results: test1, test2

**Example2 (fails):**

List of strings 1 = test1, test2, test3
; List of strings 2 = test1

Expected results: test1

```js
var checkDiagnoses = "test1, test2, test3"
var splitDiagnosesArray =checkDiagnoses.split(',');
   
$('.addDiagnoses').html($('.addDiagnoses').html().split(', ').map(function(el) {
  if (el.indexOf(splitDiagnosesArray)) {
    return '<span class="diagnosesTags">' + el + '<span class="materialIcon equalDiagnosis materialicons-Materialicon material-icons">star</span></span>'
} else {
    return '<span class="diagnosesTags">' + el + '</span>'
}

}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addDiagnoses">test1</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues:

- `.split(', ')` vs `.split(',')` will not match
- `txt.indexOf(array)` is round the wrong way
- `txt.indexOf(array)` returns -1 if not found, so must be compared with `>=0`

Giving (with some slight changes to make it a testbed, eg div->input / div.html() -> input.val())

```js
var checkDiagnoses = "test1,test2,test3"
var splitDiagnosesArray = checkDiagnoses.split(',');

$("#btn").click(function() {

  $('#output').html(
    $('.addDiagnoses').val().split(',').map(function(el) {
      el = el.trim();

      if (splitDiagnosesArray.indexOf(el) != -1) {
        return '<span class="diagnosesTags">' + el + '*</span>'
      } else {
        return '<span class="diagnosesTags">' + el + '</span>'
      }
    }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class="addDiagnoses" value='test1'></div>
<br/>
<button type='button' id='btn'>test</button>
<hr/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkDiagnoses = "test1, test2, test3"
var splitDiagnosesArray =checkDiagnoses.split(',').map(s => s.trim())

$('.addDiagnoses').html($('.addDiagnoses').html().split(',').map(function(el) {
    el = el.trim()
    if (splitDiagnosesArray.includes(el)) {
    return '<span class="diagnosesTags">' + el + '<span class="materialIcon equalDiagnosis materialicons-Materialicon material-icons">star</span></span>'
    } else {
    return '<span class="diagnosesTags">' + el + '</span>'
    }

}))
```